# C#- ArrayList problema con método

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando hacer un vector de `ArrayList` y agregándole los `ArrayList` mediante el método correspondiente, pero parace no funcionar, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Se supone que el método para agregar elemento al `ArrayList` es `Add` pero no funciona, por otro lado intenté hacerlo de otra forma, pero en ese caso no puedo acceder a los elementos.

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList { "1", "2", "3" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList { "A", "B", "C" };
ArrayList[] total = new ArrayList [] {  };

total.Add(lista1);
total.Add(lista2);
```

Segunda forma:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList { "1", "2", "3" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList { "A", "B", "C" };
ArrayList total = new ArrayList {  };

total.Add(lista1);
total.Add(lista2);

for (int cont = 0; cont < total.Count; cont++)
{
    for (int cont2=0;cont2 < total[cont].Count;cont2++   )
    {

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso del método `AddRange`:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList { "1", "2", "3" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList { "A", "B", "C" };
ArrayList total = new ArrayList {  };

total.AddRange(lista1);
total.AddRange(lista2);
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/KROF71922)</kbd>

## Actualización:

Dado tu comentario, donde mencionas que tu resultado esperado debería ser `{{A,B;C},{1,2,3}}`, entonces sugiero que hagas uso de una lista, teniendo como definición `List<ArrayList>`:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList { "1", "2", "3" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList { "A", "B", "C" };
List<ArrayList> total = new List<ArrayList>();

total.Add(lista1);
total.Add(lista2);

Console.WriteLine("Total de elementos en la lista: " + total.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Total de elementos en la posición 0: " + total[0].Count);
Console.WriteLine("Total de elementos en la posición 1: " + total[1].Count);

foreach(ArrayList item in total){
    Console.WriteLine("Elementos del ArrayList:");
    for(int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++){
        Console.WriteLine(item[i]);
    }
}
```

Aquí puedes ver la segunda <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/TYUTM21807)</kbd>

## Actualización 2:

Dado a tu segundo comentario, para hacer uso de tu código necesariamente en la segunda forma, es necesario hacer un casteo explícito para `((ArrayList)total[cont]).Count`:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList { "1", "2", "3" };
ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList { "A", "B", "C" };
ArrayList total = new ArrayList { };

total.Add(lista1);
total.Add(lista2);

for (int cont = 0; cont < total.Count; cont++)
{
    for (int cont2 = 0; cont2 < ((ArrayList)total[cont]).Count; cont++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((ArrayList)total[cont])[cont2]);
    }
}
```

Aquí puedes ver la tercer <kbd>[demostración de la solución](http://rextester.com/HXDJ44198)</kbd>

O en su caso, puedes utilizar `foreach` en lugar del `for` (hasta se ve más limpio el código ¿cierto?):

```
foreach (var cont in total)
{
    foreach (var cont2 in (ArrayList)cont)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cont2);
    }
}
```

Comment: intente hacerlo asi tambien pero el problema esta en que los datos quedan pegados es decir quedan de esta manera {A;B;C,1,2,3} en lugar de esta manera {{A,B;C},{1,2,3}} BTW gracias por el aporte igualmente se agradece.

Comment: @Shiki he actualizado la respuesta con lo que requieres :)

Comment: En la segunda forma del codigo que puse hay alguna manera de sacar los datos? es decir hay un arraylist que contiene 2 arraylist hay alguna forma de sacar esos datos?

Comment: Si quieres acceder a un ArrayList dentro de otro ArrayList, sólo tienes que hacer algo como: `miArrayList[0][0]`, así accederías al primer elemento del primer ArrayList.

Comment: @Shiki he actualizado la respuesta, revisad :D

Comment: @EmmanuelLG me temo que directamente no es posible hacerlo como lo mencionas, se requiere un casteo antes.

Comment: @Flxtr Tienes razón, olvidaba eso.

Comment: Funciona la demostracion de solucion pero lo pruebo en IDE y no funciona, igualmente me ayudo a a buscar otras opciones para resolver el problema, Flxtr y Emmanuel les agradezco el tiempo y los tips que me aportaron, muchisimas gracias!! igual voy a seguir intentando acceder a un arraylist dentro de otro, solo por curiosidad y con los codigos de aca supongo que voy a dar con el clavo, muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Shiki ¿qué error te sale?

Comment: me muestra 1 y A nada mas es como si no recorriera todo

Comment: @Shiki talvés algo falta por ahí, copia y pega el código del demo, ese funciona excelente :)

Answer (score 0):

Si no mal entiendo quiere un arreglo de arreglo. Entonces tienes que asignarle el indice, de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList lista1 = new ArrayList { "1", "2", "3" };
        ArrayList lista2 = new ArrayList { "A", "B", "C" };
        ArrayList[] total = new ArrayList[2];

        total[0] = lista1;
        total[1] =lista2;
```

Comment: Hay alguna forma de no establecer el limite del arreglo inicialmente o por decir de alguna forma que sea ilimitado?